# Large cupy array running out of GPU Ram

Tags: gpu, ram, allocation, cupy

This is a total newbie question but I've been searching for a couple days and cannot find the answer.

I am using cupy to allocate a large array of doubles (circa 655k rows x 4k columns ) which is about 16Gb in ram. I'm running on p2.8xlarge (the aws instance that claims to have 96GB of GPU ram and 8 GPUs), but when I allocate the array it gives me out of memory error.

Is this happening becaues the 96GB of ram is split into 8x12 GB lots that are only accessible to each GPU? Is there no concept of pooling the GPU ram across the GPUs (like regular ram in multiple CPU situation) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From playing around with it a fair bit, I think the answer is no, you cannot pool memory across GPUs. You can move data back and forth between GPUs and CPU but there's no concept of unified GPU ram accessible to all GPUs